# Recieving 400 bad request when trying to exchange authorization code with oauth 2 tokens

Tags: post, react-native, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to connect to an rss api provider 'Inoreader' and I'm using react native. I am able to get the authorization code but when I submit a post request for exchanging with tokens, I get 400 bad request. The response text is undefined. I checked and all their parameters are matching with my app's. I have tried. 
 This is their documentation: https://www.inoreader.com/developers/oauth

```
fetch('https://www.inoreader.com/oauth2/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Host': 'www.inoreader.com',
            'Content-length': '217',
            'User-Agent': navigator.userAgent,
            'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'code':`${this.state.auth_code}&redirect_uri=${this.state.gizmos}&client_id=${this.state.userId}&client_secret=${this.state.userKey}&scope=&grant_type=authorization_code`
        })
    })
    .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
            userName: res.access_token
        });

        console.log(res.status);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I see three problems in your code

1. You have a fixed `Content-length` value (217) from the Inoreader example. This way, the server reads just 217 characters of the request and the rest is discarded if the request is longer.
2. The request `Content-type` is `urlencoded`, but you probably don't URL encode the values. You can use the `[encodeURIComponent()][1]` function to do it.
3. The `/token` endpoint requires you to send a client secret, but your application cannot keep it safe, so the secret can easily get compromised. As they write in the guide, the request should be done from a backend. Or you can ask them to support [OAuth2 for native apps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252).

Comment: I tried the first two suggestions of yours and its not solved. Could there be a reason that the third suggestion you made is blocking my request. I understand that the secret key is vulnerable, but it should still work right? And thanks a lot for the reply :)

Comment: What did you do with the `Content-length`? Do you have a request and response log? Does the HTTP 400 response contain some additional info in its body?

Comment: I tried both: changing content-length to the actual length of request and tried removing the tag completely. The statustext of the response is showing undefined. I tried running the same in postman, it shows 403 forbidden, you need AppId even though I provided that.